# What would be the sending and Receiving servers i need to configure?

Tags: email, client-server

I have company mailid somthing like myname@company.com ,the company is someother palce (offsite),i have a mail client ie Thunderbird for linux ,when i try to create an mail account it is aasking for sending server(SMTP) name and receiving server (POP3) names.

What would be the sending and Receiving servers i need to configure ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a question for your company's IT team.  You *can* discover SMTP servers using:

`nslookup --query=MX mycompanydomain.com`

I'm assuming you're on Linux, so check that syntax as my memory's a little iffy on it.  AFAIK there is no sensible way of discovering POP servers and even the above method for SMTP servers is not good - you'll likely get more than one response and there'll almost certainly be one your IT team want you to use.